# Переопределение статического метода в Java

Tags: java, static, override

В Java нельзя переопределять статические методы. Но почему работает следующий код:

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B.fun();
    }
}

class A {
    public static void fun() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public static void fun() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

На печать выводится "B". Все выглядит так, как будто это переопределение. Потому что при перегрузке я должна была бы что-то изменить в сигнатуре метода. Но нет, я ничего не меняла.

Аннотацию "override" не могу поставить над методом.

Comment: В Java статические методы определяются во время компиляции. А подклассы загружаются после компиляции.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Начнем по порядку

### Переопределение метода:

**Переопределение метода** (*Method overriding*) это возможность языка позволяющая подклассу или дочернему элементу классу обеспечивать специфическую реализацию метода, который уже реализовали в одном из супер-классов или родительском классе. Переопределение выглядит так:

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        
        dog.voice(); // Вывод: Гав
        cat.voice(); // Вывод: Мяу
    }
}

class Animal { // родительский класс
    public void voice() {
        System.out.print("Голос животного");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal { // класс-наследник

    @Override // Переопределение метода voice() унаследованного от класса Animal в классе-наследнике Dog
    public void voice() {
        System.out.print("Гав");
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal { // класс-наследник

    @Override // Переопределение метода voice() унаследованного от класса Animal в классе-наследнике Cat
    public void voice() {
        System.out.print("Мяу");
    }

}
```

Переопределенный метод должен иметь тот же модификатор доступа что его родитель, принимать аргументы как его родитель, и иметь возвращаемый тип такой же как у его родителя

 Т.е.

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        
        dog.voice("Шарик", 10); // Вывод: Гав
        cat.voice("не Шарик", 7); // Вывод: Мяу
    }
}

class Animal {
    // Родительский метод имеет возвращаемый тип String. Принимает два параметра, типа String и int
    public String voice(String animal_name, int animal_age) {
        System.out.print("Гав");
        
        return animal_name;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
    // Переопределенный метод должен как его родитель, иметь возвращаемый тип String, и принимать параметры как его родитель 
    @Override
    public String voice(String dog_name, int dog_age) {
        System.out.print("Гав");
        
        return dog_name;
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    @Override
    public String voice(String cat_name, int cat_age) {
        System.out.print("Мяу");        
        return cat_name;
    }
}
```

### Сокрытие метода:

Сокрытие методов, грубо говоря, представляет из себя "перекрытие" методом текущего класса, метода родительского класса. Выглядит это следующим образом:

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog.voice(); // Вывод: Гав
    }
}

class Animal {
    public static void voice() {
        System.out.print("звук");
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    // Метод определенный в классе-наследнике идентичный по сигнатуре с методом родительского класса
    public static void voice() {
        System.out.print("Гав");
    }
}
```

Сигнатуры методов этих двух классов идентичны, т.е. в классе родителе `Animal` есть `public static void voice()` и в классе-наследнике `Dog` есть `public static void voice()`. Следовательно вызов `Dog.voice()` будет вызывать метод определенный в классе `Dog`
Важно отметить, что перекрытие требует таких же правил как и переопределение метода.

> Переопределенный метод должен иметь тот же модификатор доступа что его родитель, принимать аргументы как его родитель, и иметь возвращаемый тип такой же как у его родителя

т.е.

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog.voice(); // Вывод: Гав
        Dog.voice("Шарик"); // Вывод: Шарик говорит гав
    }
}

class Animal {
    public static void voice() {
        System.out.print("звук");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    
    public static void voice() { // Метод перекрывающий унаследованный метод
        System.out.print("Гав");
    }
    
    public static void voice(String name) { // Отдельный метод класса Dog
        System.out.print(name + " говорит гав");
    }
    
}
```

### Рассмотрим использование таких методов в своих классах

1. Использование без схожего по сигнатуре метода

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog.voice(); // Вывод: звук
    }
}

class Animal {
    public static void voice() {
        System.out.print("звук");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {  
    public static void dog_voice() {
        voice();
    }
}
```

Поскольку в классе-наследнике нет реализованного схожего по сигнатуре с родительским классом метода, то используется метод унаследованный от родительского класса

2. Использование схожего по сигнатуре метода

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog.dog_voice(); // Вывод: гав
    }
}

class Animal {
    public static void voice() {
        System.out.print("звук");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    
    public static void voice() {
        System.out.print("Гав");
    }
    public static void dog_voice() {
        voice();
    }
}
```

Поскольку теперь у класса `Dog` появился "свой метод" `voice()` он перекрывает метод унаследованный от `Animal`

3. Использование метода унаследованного от родителя, когда есть метод перекрывающий его

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog.dog_voice(); // Вывод: Гавзвук
    }
}

class Animal {
    public static void voice() {
        System.out.print("звук");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    
    public static void voice() { // Метод перекрывающий унаследованный метод
        System.out.print("Гав");
    }
    
    public static void dog_voice() {
        voice(); // Вызов метода voice определенного в классе Dog;
        Animal.voice(); // Вызов метода voice определенного в классе Animal 
    }
}
```

---

Хочу дополнить тем, что перекрытие работает не только с методами класса, но и с его полями. Небольшой пример:

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog.animal(); // Вывод: Имя этого животного Собакен
    }
}
class Animal {
    public static String animal_name = "Нет имени, просто животное";
    
    public static void animal() {
        System.out.print("Имя этого животного " + animal_name);
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    public static String animal_name = "Собакен"; // Перекрывает поле родительского класса Animal
    
    public static void animal() {
        System.out.print("Имя этого животного " + animal_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Но если удалить `fun` из класса B, то код `B.fun();` по прежнему будет рабоать, верно?

Comment: @tym32167 да, работать будет. И тогда будет вызываться метод унаследованный от класса `A`

Comment: @tym32167 дополнил ответ

Comment: я не хочу писать свой ответ, потому просто дам вам пару рекомендаций. Я бы рассказал, что такое "переопределение метода" - дал бы этому определение и после рассказал, что такое "сокрытие метода" и в чем месжду ними разница. После я бы показал на примере, где будет переопределение, а где сокрытие. Есть даже [ссылка на доку](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) по этому поводу. Я думаю, что такое дополнение будет отличным плюсом для вашего ответа. Как минимум я бы за такое плюс поставил :)

Comment: @tym32167 подправил ответ

Comment: Поставил плюс конечно. Еще одно дополнение, для понимания. Переопределение - это вещь, которая происходит в рантайме. То есть во время выполнения программы, JVM будет выполнять поиск нужного метода. Сокрытие же - это то, что происходит во время компиляции. То есть во время компиляции программы уже ясно, какой метод будет вызван при сокрытии.

Comment: Понятно. Значит, это сокрытие метода, а не переопределение.

Comment: @ВерховаГалина вы можете принять ответ нажав на галочку

Answer (score 1):

есть случаи когда мы осуществляем ПЕРЕОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ метода, а есть случаи когда мы осуществляем СОКРЫТИЕ метода. В твоем случае происходит "сокрытие", а не "переопределение" метода.

Статические методы НЕ "переопределяют" методы суперкласса. Статические методы умеют осуществлять "сокрытие" метода из суперкласса. На первый взгляд может ПОКАЗАТЬСЯ что "переопределение" и "сокрытие" одно и то же. [Здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) написанно в чем разница между ними.

Comment: ахах, хороший ход, держите плюс :)

Comment: Зачем вставлять текст картинкой?

Comment: @AK, не хочеться печатать еще раз. Это мой предыдущий ответ

Comment: То есть вы не умеете Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V? Нда... тяжело вам в жизни наверное, картинки постоянно вставлять и перенабирать постоянно одно и то же.

Comment: И всё-таки ловите минус. Нельзя код и текст вставлять картинками.

Comment: Хотя нет, извините: был написан текст, вы взяли его и удалили, заменили на картинку. Это вандализм. Возвращаю к предыдущей редакции, прошу так не делать. Если не знаете как правильно - спросите, не умеете - тоже можно спросить, подскажем.